# Oneiric Ubuntu Server Cloud Guest 11.10 (Ocelot) how to remote desktop in amazon aws

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, desktop

i am complete noob when comes to Linux . how can i connect remotely desktop or Gui to a a Ubuntu Server Cloud Guest 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) server in amazon aws from a windows 7 machine ,

can some one give me a link to complete tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and assume your *remote* Ubuntu instance doesn't have an X server installed -- i.e. you're using the command line version.

Download and install [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and you should be able to connect to your AWS instance using the SSH keys you initially set up.

Answer (score 0):

Also, recently AWS has added a new feature,
You can now log in to an EC2 instance from the AWS Management Console using an integrated SSH client.

- Just right on the ec2 instance from the aws management console and click on **connect** and
- select the second option  -  **Connect from your browser using the MindTerm SSH Client (Java Required)**.
- Specify the private key path and click on "launch mindterm"..  thats it.